# ASP.NET Core log-in not redirecting me to home page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am creating a login and registration with identity in asp.net core c#, I configured all the files and the database, and double checked and saw that the user is in AspNetUsers so the connection between the database and the program is working. I put when user is authenticated, it redirects to the home page but it is staying on the Log-In Page.

```
 public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) { Response.Redirect("Home"); }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
            }

            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

            // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        }
```

Comment: You are just setting the `ReturnUrl` to the value... you are not redirecting to it..

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya No

Comment: Change Response.Redirect("Home") to return RedirectToAction("Home")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify the code as below.

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
    Response.Redirect("/Home/Index");
}
```

Test Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Replace below code:

```
Response.Redirect("Home");
```

New Code :

```
return new RedirectToPageResult("/Home/Index");
```